# What is the difference in these two methods of determining NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I've got some T-SQL code that does a check to determine if a field is NULL.  Normally I simply do a IS NULL check on the field, however in this code I've been given, the method used is 
`WHERE ISNULL(MyField, '') <> ''`

Is this a more accepted method?  Is it better or worse than simply saying `WHERE MyField IS NOT NULL`

Cheers for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It accounts for both null fields and fields with an empty string. In some cases this is desired over just a null field.

Comment: I don't have the experience to adequately answer the question, but based on my programming experience it would be very minimal as it would have to make one more check to see if the final value is not an empty string.  This can be done very quickly because if the string is not of length zero then the field is not null or an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
WHERE MyField IS NOT NULL
```

would allow the optimizer to use an index, if appropriate (even if available, it might not be the best solution).  A function on a field generally prevents an index from being used.

The expressions:

```
ISNULL(MyField, '') <> ''
```

or

```
COALESCE(MyField, '') <> ''
```

not only confuse `''` with `NULL`.  But, if the field is a numeric type, then `''` will be interpreted as `0`, causing further confusion.